# fgetc(): Is it enough to just check EOF?

Tags: c, file-io

In various examples found on the web `fgetc()` is used like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(PATH, "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("main");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int ch;

while (ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF) {
    // do something
}
```

But according to the manpage to fgetc()

> If a read error occurs, the error
>   indicator for the stream shall be set,
>   fgetc() shall return EOF, [CX]   and
>   shall set errno to indicate the error.

So need I check this too? And how?

Comment: You need parentheses around the assignment: `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)`, but with that fix in place, it is sufficient to check for just EOF.  You will get EOF on error or actual EOF; if you want to, you can disambiguate the two cases after the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check it with ferror(3), right after the while:

```
while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)))
   // do something

if (ferror(fp) != 0)
   // error handling
```

ferror returns a non-zero if an error occured.

If you want use fp after an error occured, you'll need to clear the error flag with clearerr:

```
clearerr(fp);
```

Comment: @Helper Method: You just quoted that very statement in your manpage excerpt.

Comment: Is comparing AND assigning like this (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp))) considered a good practice? I am learning this language feature via Beej's guide to C (https://beej.us/guide/bgc/html/split/file-inputoutput.html)  who suggests this approach but find contradicting advice at a page from the CMU (https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP45-C.+Do+not+perform+assignments+in+selection+statements). Can anyone help me clarify?

Answer (score 10):

This is what the specs say:

> the fgetc() function shall obtain the next byte as an unsigned char converted to an int
>
> The following macro name shall be defined as a negative integer constant expression: EOF

As long as you store the return value in an `int` and not a `char`, it is sufficient to check for `EOF` because it is guaranteed not to represent a valid character value.

---

Also, in your code, this:

```
while (ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF)
```

should be:

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```

The additional parentheses are required because `!=` has higher precedence than `=`.

Answer (score 6):

Looping until `fgetc` returns `EOF` is perfectly fine. Afterwards, if you want to know whether the loop ended due to simply reaching the end of the file or due to an error, you should call `ferror` or `feof`. If you don't care you can skip the call.

Note that it matters whether you check `feof` or `ferror`, because the error indicator for a stream is sticky and can evaluate true even when hitting eof was the cause of `fgetc` failure. Normally you should use `feof` to check, and if it returns false, conclude that the loop stopped due to a new error.