# Redirecting stdin

Tags: c, io, stdin

I compile my code then run:  $ ./a.exe < input.txt
For some reason it doesn't read the first character (t is missing from test in first line)
and there is also a weird character at the end. How do I combat these two errors?
 Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {    
    char c = getchar();    
    while (c != EOF){
        printf("%c ",c); 
        c = getchar();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Sample execution:

```
$ ./a.exe < input.txt
  e s t   l i n e   o n e
 t e s t   l i n e   t w o
 f i n a l   l i n e ▒
```

Comment: 2all the answering people: please stop using "char c" in your snippets. All char-related functions take and return ints, not chars, and so is EOF. int c -- correct, char c -- wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that when you `while` first executes, c is unassigned.

Then, notice that when the next-to-last character is read, your `while` test will pass, resulting in reading and printing another character - so you are seeing the visual representation of the EOF as the last character.

If you are piping a file into this program, I suspect something before the lines you wrote is resulting in the T being omitted.

You could avoid the other problems by doing something like:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void) {    
        int c = getchar();    
        while (c != EOF){
            printf("%c ",c); 
            c = getchar();
        }
        return (0);
    }
```

Edit: I would also suggest we follow  user3125367's suggestion in the comment above, which eliminates some sneaky casting from int to char. I've edited above to use int. This may also let you use the %n to see what the actual value of the first character is in your file, and/or it may solve the problem (i.e., the first character in your file may have looked like a T, but been a non-ASCII character with a value greater than 255.)

Comment: This is a good example of a case where a do-while construct can be more useful and easier to read than just a while.

Comment: Your solution fixed the EOF showing up at the end, but the first character is still omitted. http://gyazo.com/a66ebc666b56cbc381b6ff4bea8408bf

Comment: Edit the question to show us the code before the code you showed. I think it must happen before then.

Comment: my whole program is just those lines, nothing more

Comment: Either that, or your input file could be interesting. It looks like there IS a character being read, but it's not displaying as anything visible. You could switch the program to display the integer character code value of each character, to see what it thinks the first character is.

Comment: i.e. try printf("%n ",c);

Comment: that gives: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: okay so using ints worked when I made the output integers for the ASCII values, there it was able to show the t as 116, but printing as %c still skips the t. Any idea? Just curious, thanks

Comment: Hmm, odd. 116 is t, so I think it should work. You could put printf("Output:\n"); before the code, to see if it is just something weird with your shell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything remarkable about redirecting stdin.  It looks like your text file effectively has ASCII characters (is that right--no strange symbols?).  The file may be encoded as UTF-8 (up to 4 bytes per character) or another multibyte system.  For UTF-8 the values of the ASCII characters are preserved, i.e. all less than 128, so they can be converted to signed char without loss of precision.  In general though, a character in UTF-8 could be up to 4 bytes in size, thus requiring  storage at least the size of int.
  Your code is a bit awkward, but I don't see right away why it shouldn't work unless the char type is the problem.  However, I tried with both int and char and got the same result (it worked fine). Here's my code (with the char type commented out):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{//char c; // Wrong.  getchar returns int.
   int  c;
   while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) printf("%c", c);
   return 0;
}
```

The output was the same for either char c; or int c; as follows:

```
Test line 1
Test line 2
Last Line, no CR
```

Edit: The alternating spaces indicate that your input.txt file must be encoded as UCS-2 (two byte Unicode), or something similar; every other byte is a zero since your text character values are all less than 127.  The zeros print as spaces since they are "unprintable."  I'm guessing here (don't have time to check it out) that the leading space on your first output line is due to a two byte BOM (Byte Order Mark), either FF FE or FE FF, which are likely to be unprintable.  Save your input file as UTF-8 or ANSI and try again.

Comment: Did you edit your coded since posting the original question?  Also, did you type the alternating spaces in input.txt, or are they an artifact of the code?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure how the first error is happening, but this should fix the second one:

```
int c;   
for (c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar()) {
    printf("%c ",c);          
}
```

Double check to make sure that your file does infact contain the first character you are missing.

The reason you use `int` when reading characters with `getchar` is because the [**EOF**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/) constant is an integer and it is [not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4292804/2089675) to represent a valid character value. So when you compare your character to EOF, even if you have encountered EOF, it will not evaluate to true when compared to the actual EOF constant.

You will also notice that those functions you use such as `getchar`, `putchar`, etc, all take and return `int`s not `char` (I know, confusing right?). I believe this decision was made primarily so that support of EOF can be added without sacrificing precious bytes.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/15a2e749bc2d0949e20d14583d0ad0ec , also why does you solution fix the character at end?

Comment: @ImBadAtProgramming The c != EOF; part of the for statement would prevent the EOF from printing.