# problem in copying one file contents to another in c

Tags: c, file

I am trying to copy contents of one file to another character by character using a loop.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main(){
    
    FILE * fp1=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    FILE * fp2=fopen("file2.txt","w");
    
    char c;
    while(!feof(fp1)){
       c=fgetc(fp1);
       fputc(c,fp2);
       }
   return 0;
  }
```

Consider that we have `hello` in the file1, after running the code the content present in file2 is `hello�`.

Why I am getting this extra character (`�`)? Is there anything wrong with my piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

`feof` returns non-zero value after `fgetc` returns `EOF`. Therefore, the program has `fputc` the `EOF` returned by `fgetc`.

You can do the following.

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
    fputc(c, fp2);
}
```

Use `int` instead of `char` for `c` to be able to determine the value `EOF`.

Comment: fgetc returns EOF even when an error occurs . feof returns non zero value only when end of file is reached but it works concurrently. Which is better one to use ??

Comment: You can use ferror() or feof() after the loop.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292729/fgetc-is-it-enough-to-just-check-eof